# Add Cart button not working correctly for all products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, wordpress-shortcode

I'm working on a custom WordPress theme with woo-commerce features. I need to add a cart button on the shop page, but it does not appear correctly: the button can add only the first one, also the product is added automatically after refreshing the page that which I don't understand. Could someone help me, please?

```html
<?php
$args = array('post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 12);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

<div class="">
   <h6 class=""> <?= get_the_title(); ?> </h6>
   <p class=""> <?= get_price(); ?> </p>
   <?= do_shortcode('[add_to_cart id='.get_the_ID().']'); ?>
</div>

<?php 
endwhile;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the configuration of the products. Maybe you selected *Affilitelink* instead of a physical product. Or the products have different variations. Then the button "Read more" is also displayed.

It this will not help you have to add the code of`do_shortcode` to your description.

Comment: Thanks Melanie for your answer. The configuration of the products is ok. I'm working with simple product, there is no variation. Also I tried what's it's suggested in the link below but I usually having the same appear

Comment: [link] ( https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/add-product-to-cart-programmatically.html?unapproved=7566&moderation-hash=88ce22550d0cb76e5d631177036ee9de#comment-7566 )